# Run code for a period of time

Tags: javascript

Tried to search for something like this and just could not find exactly what im after so sorry if this has been already answered somewhere.

I need to run a bit of code **for** a period of time, **not after** a period of time.
Basically i want to display a random value from an array fast on the page and i want to this to keep showing for 1 minute and then stop.

The code below will only start after 3 seconds, and does not stop and im not sure how can i achieve this, so any help much appreciated.

```
var messages = ["Good!", "Great!", "Awesome!", "Super!", "Nice!"];
    function getMessage() {
       return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    }
    setTimeout(function () { oneSecondFunction(); }, 3000);
    function oneSecondFunction() {
        $('#test').html(getMessage());
        setTimeout('oneSecondFunction()', 100);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by stop running? The example code modifys the dom and finishs.

Comment: @user1937198 - No, it modifies the dom, _schedules itself for 100 ms later_, and finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var messages = ["Good!", "Great!", "Awesome!", "Super!", "Nice!"];

function getMessage() {
    return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
}

var interval = null;
setTimeout(function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        // Your code here
        $("#test").html(getMessage());
    }, 100);

    //Stop the functions after 1 minute.
    setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(interval); }, 60 * 1000);
}, 3000);
```

This will create an interval after 3 seconds, which will execute the code every 100ms for 1 minute.

Comment: +1 for what is probably the most JavaScript-ish solution. You could move the declaration of `interval` as well as the second `setTimeout` call (that clears the interval) into the first `setTimeout` function. Then you have a properly self-contained closure (and don't need the extra `+ 3000` in the later time-out). P.S. OP wants the updates to continue for one minute, not three.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement suggestion, I edited the solution. I think i have messed up with the 3 seconds in my mind...

Answer (score 2):

Set a second timeout for the end time that sets a flag and only reschedule `oneSecondFunction` if the flag is not set:

```
var messages = ["Good!", "Great!", "Awesome!", "Super!", "Nice!"];
var stop = false;
function getMessage() {
   return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
}
setTimeout(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { stop = true; }, 60000); // one minute later
    oneSecondFunction();
}, 3000);
function oneSecondFunction() {
    $('#test').html(getMessage());
    if (!stop) {
        setTimeout('oneSecondFunction()', 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of how much time has passed since the first time the function ran, and when that period becomes larger than one minute simply do not renew the `setTimeout` call.

For example:

```
var timeStarted;

function getMessage() {
   return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
}

setTimeout(function () { oneSecondFunction(); }, 3000);

function oneSecondFunction() {
    var now = Date.now();
    timeStarted = timeStarted || now;

    $('#test').html(getMessage());

    if (now - timeStarted < 60000) {
        setTimeout(oneSecondFunction, 100); // you can just write function's name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to track how much time the function is running. Then you test if the time is over. Here's an exemple of how you can do it.

```
var messages = ["Good!", "Great!", "Awesome!", "Super!", "Nice!"],
    interval = 100,
    delay = 0;

    function getMessage() {
       return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    }
    setTimeout(oneSecondFunction, 3000); // Less code is better.

    function oneSecondFunction() {
        $('#test').html(getMessage());
        delay+= interval;
        if (delay < (3 * 60 * 1000)) { // 3 minutes
             setTimeout(oneSecondFunction, interval);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't setTimeout from oneSecondFunction to achieve make a loop.  Instead use the setInterval function and pass the function you want to call and how long you want to sleep to it.  Then call clearInterval with the interval ID to stop it.  Like this:

```
function getMessage() {
return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
}

 function oneSecondFunction() {
 $("#test").html(getMessage());
}
var intervalID = setInterval(oneSecondFunction, <Delay between runs in millis here>);
function stop() {
clearInterval(intervalID);
}
setTimeout(stop, 60000);
```

Comment: This is flawed because it doesn't wait the required three seconds before starting the 100ms interval. Otherwise, how is this different from [Simon Fischer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19212164/535871)?